# Send span content to site via parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a site where u can learn languages and have a problem with the cloze function I really want to have on it.
At first I'm using JSP to generate the HTML for the site so it have to be a solution which only need JS and HTML.

Here the code I currently have:

```css
span.edit {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #000000;
 font-weight: bolder;
    border-color: #f4f4f4 #f4f4f4 #000000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    min-width: 80px;
    padding: 1px;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

span.edit[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
 font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: italic;
 color: #848484;
}

.sentence{
 min-width: 250px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="cloze">
 <h2>Cloze</h2>
 <div class="text">
  <p>Lorem <span contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="eingabe" id="var1" class="edit" title=""></span> dolor sit amet <span contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="eingabe" id="var2" class="edit" title=""></span>. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea <span contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="eingabe" id="var3" class="edit" title=""></span>.</p>
  <p>Dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut.</p>
  <a href="#">Send to site</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now my question: how do I send the content of the span-fields to a site so that I can get the Parameters from it?

I know u can use a form with input-fields but I think it's not good if You have a long text with some words in it.

Thank You for your answers!

Comment: you can use a comon class on all span then loop throught yhis class like $('.className').each and in the loop if you want to get content of sapn then write this $(this).html()

Comment: Thank You! That really helped me alot :)

Comment: please upvote the comment if possible :)

Comment: Seems you can't vote comments :/ but do you have an Idea for the sending problem (my answer on this topic)

Comment: you can use query strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a class on the button, triggered on click and parsed all class 'edit' fields. But I still have a problem with sending the parameters via POST to my Site. Any Ideas for that?

```
$(".proofCloze").on("click", function(e){
    var parameters = '';
    $('.edit').each(function() {
        parameters = parameters + "'"+$(this).attr("id") + "':'" + $(this).html() + "', ";
    });
    parameters = parameters.substring(0, parameters.length-2);
    parameters = '{'+parameters+'}';
    alert('Address: '+$(this).attr("href")+"\nParameter: "+parameters);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use button instead of anchor tag
`<button type="button" id="submit">Send to site</button>`

```
var btn = document.getElementById('submit');

// Bind Click event to the button/trigger
btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
   // Retrieve the span value
   var var1 = document.getElementById('var1').textContent;
   var var2 = document.getElementById('var2').textContent;
   var var3 = document.getElementById('var3').textContent;

   // Send the parameters here
   console.log(var1, var2, var3);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajax from jQuery or native javascript ajax feature to post the values to the server file which will process the span data on clicking `<a>` tag.

Also ensure that you retrieve the span element values and send it as POST to avoid maximum limit size.